# Removing item from div by checking against value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to add/remove input items from a hidden div that have a matching value from an array. The array by default is empty, but a value is added to it when an li item is clicked. I would like to be able to remove the input item that corresponds to the value that is currently in the array.

Currently my code works, if you delete the items in the same order you've added them. I am looking to have this function where you can remove and add any input in any order. Can someone help me out?

Below is my js:

```
var downloadArray = [];
var addToArray = function addToArray(src){  
    downloadArray.push(src);

        //If the input value matches the download Array, remove it
        if (downloadArray == $('.result input').attr("value")) {
            $('input[value="' + downloadArray + '"]').remove();
            console.log(downloadArray);

            //Empties array 
            downloadArray = [];
        } else {
            //Attaches value to array
            var result = '<input type="hidden" class="hiddenValue" name="asset[]" value="' + downloadArray + '" />';
            $('.result').append(result);
            console.log(downloadArray);
            //Empties array 
            downloadArray = [];
        }
};
```

and below is my html:

```
    <form action="compare_arrays_in_dir.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li class="add" onclick="addToArray('file1.psd');"><span>Add File 1</span></li>
            <li class="add" onclick="addToArray('file2.psd');"><span>Add File 2</span></li>
            <li class="add" onclick="addToArray('file3.psd');"><span>Add File 3</span></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="result" id="result"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

UPDATE: Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4fk60ss/3/)

Comment: Could you provide a working JSFiddle?

Comment: yes provide us a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f4fk60ss/3/

Answer (score 1):

first your code and naming is very confusing, so I changed it a little.

- Add becomes Toggle (that is what it actually does)
- For the added hidden element, I made it visible for test purposes
- Also you should use ID for unique identifiers only, so I changed it to CLASS.

Here is the JS code:

```
var resultsArray = [];
function toogleInResults(src) {
    // Try to find src in array
  var idx = resultsArray.indexOf(src);
  //If it is already there, remove it
  if  (idx >= 0) {
    $('input[value="' + src + '"]').remove();
    resultsArray.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
    // Add the corresponding html for this src
    var result = '<input class="hiddenValue" name="asset[]" value="' + src + '" />';
    $('.result').append(result);
    // Add src to the array
    resultsArray.push(src);
  }
};
```

And the modified HTML:

```
<form action="compare_arrays_in_dir.php" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li class="add" onclick="toogleInResults('file1.psd');"><span>Add File 1</span></li>
    <li class="add" onclick="toogleInResults('file2.psd');"><span>Add File 2</span></li>
    <li class="add" onclick="toogleInResults('file3.psd');"><span>Add File 3</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="result" id="result"></div>

</form>
```

This is very basic so I suggest you to study more about js/html/jQuery (if this is not for study purposes already). Have a nice day!!

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ggcefqzf/) is a working JSFiddle.

Comment: thank you so much! I knew it had something to do with slice but was unsure of the syntax.